# How to display text on video from a csv in python

Tags: python, opencv, video, subtitle

I have a video and a transcript for that video in a csv file. Are there any python tools to show this video while overlaying text from the csv file, like subtitles?

I have used the imshow() tools with OpenCV to overlay text onto webcam feeds, but can that be done with pre-recorded video as well, or is there another, more efficient way to approach this that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html)
tutorial from OpenCV docs to play pre-recorded videos from files. To add text, simply use the [putText](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-puttext-method/) method to apply text to the frame before using imshow() to display it.